# CSS Sprites displaying wrong image - works in localhost

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, sprite

The server is removing a space between the background-position properties of my sprites which is causing the sprites to display only the first image of the sprite instead of the image they should be displaying. this used to work fine on the server and it still works fine on my localhost. i haven't made any changes to the server though ... any suggestions?

website is http://hiphopvip.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bug in your minimizing script the script that minify your css files , it replace every space by '-' that's why the  background-position doesn't work the way it's supposed to.

What class are you using for miminizing your css?